# Bounded curvature convex functionals

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

$\renewcommand{\Re}{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\X}{\mathcal{X}}$
Let $r:\Re^n \to \Re$ be a functional with the following properties:

1. $r$ is convex: $r(tx + (1-t)y) \leq tf(x) + (1-t)f(y)$ for all $\lambda\in[0,1]$ and $x\in\Re^n$
2. $r$ is positive homogeneous: $r(cx) = cr(x)$ for $c\geq 0$ and $x\in\Re^n$
3. $r$ is monotone: $r(x)\leq r(y)$, whenever $x \leq y$ element-wise
4. For $c$ constant, $r(x+c) = c + r(x)$ for all $x\in\Re^n$

Under assumptions 1 and 2, we know that $r$ is subadditive; for all $x,y\in\Re^n$, we have $r(x+y)\leq r(x) + r(y)$.

I wonder under what conditions, there is a $\kappa>0$ so that $r$ satisfies a bound of the form:

$$\begin{align}
\kappa (r(x) + r(y)) \leq r(x+y)
\end{align}\tag{1}\label{1}$$

for all $x,y > 0$ (element-wise).

Roughly speaking, such an inequality would serve as a bound on the curvature of $r$.

Function $r$ may not be differentiable, but it is reasonable to assume that it is lower semicontinuous. Given the assumptions stated above, $r$ can be written as

$$r(x) = \sup_{z\in A}z'x,$$

where $A$ is a closed convex set of vectors $z\geq 0$.

**Update.** If there exists a $\kappa>0$ such that \eqref{1} is satisfied, then,
$$0< \kappa \leq \inf_{x,y > 0} \frac{r(x+y)}{r(x) + r(y)}=: \kappa^\ast$$

It suffices that $\kappa^\ast$ is positive.

Suppose that $r$ is continuous. We have $\lim_{X\to 0^+}\frac{r(X+Y)}{r(X)+r(Y)} = 1$ and in light of the Moore-Osgood Theorem we have $\lim_{X,Y\to 0^+}\frac{r(X+Y)}{r(X)+r(Y)}=1$. For any $X,Y>0$, we have $\frac{r(X+Y)}{r(X)+r(Y)} > 0$. It remains to study how $r$ behaves at the horizon (as $X$ and/or $Y$ diverge to infinity).